# Repeated messages in R Console from Antidote (French Dictionary) Software

Tags: r, console

Me: R version 3.50, Mac OS X 10.13.4

I'm not sure why my French spelling and grammar checker is getting involved with R at all, and I'm assuming that's what's causing the problem.

Specifically, I use Antidote (https://www.antidote.info/en) as a spelling and grammar checker for when I'm writing in French. It has several plugins that you'd expect: Safari, Chrome, Word, etc. It's also available from an icon in the right side of the menu bar. Shouldn't affect R at all.

However, when I start R.app, I get the following in my console without interruption:

```
.
.
.
    2018-06-05 00:20:53.998 R[40909:2097800] Antidote - Texteurs: Module texteur installé dans /Applications/R.app (org.R-project.R)
2018-06-05 00:21:04.089 R[40909:2097800] Antidote - Texteurs: Module texteur installé dans /Applications/R.app (org.R-project.R)
2018-06-05 00:21:14.117 R[40909:2097800] Antidote - Texteurs: Module texteur installé dans /Applications/R.app (org.R-project.R)
2018-06-05 00:21:24.162 R[40909:2097800] Antidote - Texteurs: Module texteur installé dans /Applications/R.app (org.R-project.R)
2018-06-05 00:21:34.288 R[40909:2097800] Antidote - Texteurs: Module texteur installé dans /Applications/R.app (org.R-project.R)
.
.
.
```

It started before what you see above and continues well after.

I did notice one other red warning in the console amidst a hundred of these:

```
objc[40909]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff8d061c90) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x11a502cd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

...but I think that's unrelated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

1. Quit R
2. Launch Antidote
3. Click on the **Antidote 9** menu, then on **Preferences**
4. In the left column, click on **Context** menu
5. In the right pane, click on the **Options...** button
6. Click on the little **+** sign
7. Navigate to your Applications folder and Choose R
8. Confirm